# How to give a CCSprite an specified alpha channel?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0, alphablending

I want to create a paint-pen in Cocos2D.
and I have a png file which specify the alpha channel value of a image.(only one channel)
I want to give the alpha value to a ccsprite's texture which is pure color. and make use of the ccsprite unit as pan.to draw on the screen.

How can I do it in programming?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

I have to do this for my project too. I came up with this idea. (in cocos2d-x)

1. render your 'alpha sprite' with rgb disabled but alpha enabled(through glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE)) to a CCRenderTexture.
2. render your actual sprite with a disabled but rgb enabled (through glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_FALSE))
3. now you have rgb from actual sprite and a from 'alpha sprite', then you set the alpha blend properties of the sprite of the render texture to {GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA}.
4. now you can add the render texture and draw it to the scene.

I have tried this, this worked for my project. hope this will work for yours too.

Answer (score 1):

```
sprite.opacity = 100;
```

opacity range is 0-255. You can't change alpha of a texture and all sprites using the texture at once, unless you write a custom shader.

Comment: Thank u very much, but i want to give the sprite a alpha map, the alpha value at different pixels are different. How can I do it ?